elasticsearch-py add delay between retries
I'm instantiating a python elasticsearch client as follows
es = Elasticsearch(
        hosts=ELASTICSEARCH_URL,
        timeout=5,
        ignore_unavailable=True,
        # connection_retries=Retry(
        #     total=5,
        #     backoff_factor=1.1,
        #     status_forcelist=[429, 502, 503, 504],
        #     raise_on_status=False,
        # )
)

I want to introduce a retry delay between retries (and ideally with a backoff factor).
So that executing a search request, is retried with a backoff factor
es.search(index="abc", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})

Any ideas how to achieve this?

You can simply use tenacity lib for this simply do this
See ref to docs
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from tenacity import retry, wait_exponential, stop_after_attempt, retry_if_exception_type

# defining a retry strategy with exp 
@retry(
    retry=retry_if_exception_type(Exception),
    wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=1, min=4, max=10),
    stop=stop_after_attempt(5)
)
def retry_func(es, index, body):
    return es.search(index=index, body=body)

# Your Elasticsearch client
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}],
    timeout=5,
    CLOUD=ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID # <- if you have multiple instances 
)

try:
    response = retry_func(es, "abc", {"query": {"match_all": {}}})
    print(response)
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(f"error message: {e}")


This didn't work, Retry's total & backoff factor are completely ignored. Can be seen by activating debug logs:

which part didn't work both? bulk helpers is a library that as being tested for a while, I am sure it does perhaps your implementation. did you read the docs at all? can you also include the ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID in your client sometimes the client might not know which instance it should update or do a retry/backoff on, i.e. if you have multiple instances. Since you are seeing it in the logs then something is wrong with your code. you can provide more code so we can debug.

My sincere apologies, I have not specified in the question I need the retry on a search request. I updated the Question accordingly
